# Unable save image locally with PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use PHP CURL to save this image to my computer, but isnt working, any help would be appreciated.
Image to Save:
https://s.yimg.com/aw/api/res/1.2/MRhsVBj10l4TrtNg5j7eBA--/YXBwaWQ9eXR3YXVjdGlvbnNlcnZpY2U7aD0xNTA7cT04NTtzcj0xLjI7c3M9MS4yO3c9MjAw/http://nevec-img.zenfs.com/prod/tw_ec05-7/258e866a-b39a-471d-8e6c-62801cbccd9d.jpg

My Curl function:

```
function grab_image($url,$saveto){
        $ch = curl_init ($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
        $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        if(file_exists($saveto)){
                ($saveto);
        }
        $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
        fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
        fclose($fp);

}
```

I am pretty sure the permission for the place to save to is 777 because I can save image from other website without any problem.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a HTTPS request, please add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`

If you want to know what's going on, add `$errmsg  = curl_error($ch);` before `curl_close`, and then `echo $errmsg;`.

Comment: Hi,Jens-André Koch, The curl_error returns Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl

Comment: Is the PHP extension "php_sockets" enabled?

Comment: Hi,Jens-André Koch, it is enabled,I checked phpinfo and see Sockets Support enabled

Comment: Sorry for my stupid， there is a space in front of the url. thanx for ur help Jens